# Modify IP address in email header

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am looking to modify a form that allows a user to input their email address into a form, and when submitted, sends an email to a mailing list company, with the from address set to the inserted email address, inserting the client email address into a newsletter mailing list.(This is done with their permission, we are the only people who have access to the mailing list)

I do this currently using the System.Net.Mail.MailMessage class.

I am looking to modify this code to send the IP address of the client in the email header, instead of our servers IP, to allow us to focus our newsletters based on what country the client is from.

The email service we are using records the IP address from the Email header, so I am looking for a way to modify this before sending the email to the service.

Comment: I'd talk to your newsletter service to see if they can offer an API for you to use instead. You could fake an SMTP hop through your servers but its possible they'd use the connection IP not that IP anyway.

Comment: If your provider uses SPF then you'll run into problems too; the email will "appear" to be from a different server than the one that sent it. The reasons for spoofing the IP address (i.e. playing with Received: from headers) don't seem to be very clear - it's likely that many receiving servers will have a problem with the ip address not matching too.

Comment: Unfortunately the service we are using is Aweber, they don't support any asp.net API. I tried setting up the 3rd party one at http://aweber.codeplex.com/ however the OAuth authorization kept refusing us access. I am guessing Aweber made some update to their system, which hasn't been implemented to the API yet, however I cant be certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a 'IP address' header used for SMTP - the remote server will probably just be looking at what IP address the connection is coming from, which there is nothing you can do about (short of just bouncing it off a different server)

The header you see in your mail client won't be all of the headers sent in the original request, and can have extras added by the mail service.

Comment: OK, thanks, I guess I will have to come up with something else.

Appreciate the help.